# How can values from the tests in the interface be passed on to Java code?

Tags: java, parameters, fitnesse

I work on some tests for several games. Most of the games have identical tests, only some values (constants in my java code) are different.

Under these circumstances, I decided to reuse the class and create separate test pages in FitNesse interface for the games. The problem is to identify the correct game that is being tested in the Java code, so that the appropriate values are set.

I have considered several approaches, and currently I created in each of the tests a new column with the name of the game (in fact, an input parameter) and I set the constants in the code in accordance with this parameter's value.

I would like to know though if there is a way to send an attribute/variable from the interface to the Java code in a hidden way, so that the user doesn't need to put those values in the table.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  The title says to pass a value from the tests (I assume you mean a value on a test page), but then you say it should be hidden - does this mean it is not on the test page?

Comment: Yes, it's a value on a test page. I was thinking of hiding it from the user, keeping the implementation from him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a hidden section on the test page:

```
!*****< This is HIDDEN, but is ACTIVE
|myspecialfixture|
|game|tictactoe|

******!
```

In this example, `myspecialfixture` would save the game name somewhere that your other fixtures could access it, e.g.:

```
public class MySpecialFixture extends DoFixture {
    public static String currentGame;
    public void game(String gameName) { currentGame = gameName; }
}

public class SomeOtherFixture ... {
    ... if (MySpecialFixture.currentGame.equals( ... ) { }

}
```

Comment: I need to access it from java, how can I do that? Is it an input parameter?

Comment: Should I set a different value in interface for each test I have?

Comment: I added an example using a static variable.

Comment: This code throws NullPointerException. The idea is very good though, and I changed it to have a normal getter and setter for currentGame and adjusted the test page accordingly. And it worked!